# Extract single feature from sf-object

Tags: r, r-sf

I am looking for an efficient method for extracting a single feature from an sf-object, when the feature is given as variable name. If we have an sf-object such as:

```
g = st_as_sf(data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 5:1, a = 6:10, b = 11:15), coords = c("x", "y"))
```

we can easily extract the column a with `g$a` . However, I am wondering what is the most efficient method for extracting the column `a` if I want to use a variable `colname = "a"` instead. g[, colname] will return an sf-object with `a` as the only feature. It is possible to convert the object to a data.frame and then extract the column with `data.frame(g)[, colname]`. However, this is not very efficient. as shown with microbenchmark:

```
microbenchmark(g$a, data.frame(g)[, "a"])
```

Of course the nano-seconds in this case are rarely of interest, but for frequent extractions of larger objects, the call to data.frame(g) will have an impact on the total run time. Is there a more efficient method in this case, other than creating another object `gg=data.frame(g)`?

Answer (score 2):

As `sf` still is `data.frame` (or `tibble`), there's no need for manual conversion. Just switch between `[]` and `[[]]`, depending on if you need a column as vector or `sf` object with single feature where geometry is still attached:

```r
ne <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")
names(ne)[1:10]
#>  [1] "featurecla" "scalerank"  "labelrank"  "sovereignt" "sov_a3"    
#>  [6] "adm0_dif"   "level"      "type"       "admin"      "adm0_a3"
(sel_col <- names(ne)[9])
#> [1] "admin"

# sf with 1 feature colum and geomery column:
ne[sel_col] |> str()
#> Classes 'sf' and 'data.frame':   177 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ admin   : chr  "Fiji" "United Republic of Tanzania" "Western Sahara" "Canada" ...
#>  $ geometry:sfc_MULTIPOLYGON of length 177; first list element: List of 3
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : num [1:8, 1:2] 180 180 179 179 179 ...
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : num [1:9, 1:2] 178 178 179 179 178 ...
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : num [1:5, 1:2] -180 -180 -180 -180 -180 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "MULTIPOLYGON" "sfg"
#>  - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
#>  - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "admin"

# feature as a vector: 
ne[[sel_col]] |> str()
#>  chr [1:177] "Fiji" "United Republic of Tanzania" "Western Sahara" "Canada" ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve the issue. It is a bit slower than the dollar sign operator, but an order of magnitude faster than other methods!

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
colname = 'a'
g[c(colname, 'geometry')]
```

... if you want to keep the attribute **a** plus geometry?

If you actually want to drop the geometry (converting features to non-spatial dataframe rows), you can do so by:

```
as.data.frame(us)[colname]
```

Comment: Thanks, what I needed was without geometry, the solution by margusl seems to be the fastest that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities come to my mind, but none seems as a true gamechanger from benchmarking point of  view...

```r
microbenchmark(g$a, 
               data.frame(g)[, "a"], 
               g[, "a", drop = T],
               st_drop_geometry(g)[, "a"],
               data.table::as.data.table(g)[, "a"],
               dplyr::pull(g, "a")
               )
```

The `[` method of `{sf}` with the parameter `drop` set to true seems kind of fastest, but still does not compare to the dollar sign operator.

Comment: Thanks, anyway it is a nice comparison! The solution by margusl above is around 5 times slower than the dollar sign method, but 1/10 of the fastest of other methods.